# problemas con insertar registros en Android

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite

Tengo un problema al ingresar `usuario` y `password`, por consola arroja lo siguiente:

> table usuarios has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied

y en el emulador se detiene la app, la tabla fue creada con dos campos y un id auto increment, uso android studio, adjunto código

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("create table usuarios(codigo integer primary key autoincrement, usuario text, contrasena text)");
   db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('admin', 'admin')");
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionVieja, int versionNueva)
 {
  db.execSQL("create table usuarios(codigo integer primary key autoincrement, usuario text, contrasena text)");
   db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('admin', 'admin')");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ademas de las otras respuestas puedes también hacer el insert

```
insert into table values (null, valor_1, valor2)
```

Segun la documentacion de `sqlite` ESTA es la forma ya que cuando se declara de por si un campo INTEGER PRIMARY KEY este ya es autoincremenable.

> (1) How do I create an AUTOINCREMENT field.
>
> Short answer: A column declared INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will
>   autoincrement.
>
> If you declare a column of a table to be INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then
>   whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is
>   automatically converted into an integer.

En español :

> (1) Como crear un campo AUTOINCREMENT
>
> Respuesta corta : Cuando la columna es declarada como INTEGER PRIMARY
>   KEY esta se autoincrementara.
>
> Si se declara una columna en la tabla como INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cada
>   vez que se inserte un NULL dentro de ese valor, el valor NULL
>   automaticamente se convierte en un entero que es el mayor de todos los
>   valores de esa columna.

Answer (score 0):

El mismo mensaje de error te indica el problema:

> table usuarios has 3 columns but 2 values were supplied

La tabla usuarios contiene 3 columnas pero en tu query defines únicamente 2:

```
db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values('admin', 'admin')")
```

Aquí la **[solución](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/insert.php)** es definir los campos que deseas insertar

```
"insert into usuarios(usuario, contrasena) values('admin', 'admin')"
```

---

Esta sería la solución:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   db.execSQL("create table usuarios(codigo integer primary key autoincrement, usuario text, contrasena text)");
   db.execSQL("insert into usuarios(usuario, contrasena) values('admin', 'admin')");
}



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionVieja, int versionNueva)
 {
  db.execSQL("create table usuarios(codigo integer primary key autoincrement, usuario text, contrasena text)");
   db.execSQL("insert into usuarios(usuario, contrasena) values('admin', 'admin')");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

La sintaxis de Inserción parece incorrecta teniendo en cuenta el `AUTOINCREMENT` 
. Para solucionarlo podría especificar los campos a rellenar en su consulta

```
db.execSQL("insert into usuarios(usuario,contrasena) values('admin', 'admin')");
```

O pasando le valor `NULL` . De acuerdo a la  [Documentación](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

> Si se declara una columna de una tabla para ser `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` , a continuación, cada vez que se inserta un valor `NULL` en la columna de la tabla, el `NULL` se convierte automáticamente en un número entero que es uno mayor que el mayor valor de esa columna sobre todas las otras filas de la tabla, o 1 si la tabla está vacía

```
db.execSQL("insert into usuarios values(null,'admin', 'admin')");
```